# Recursive monad execution with cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats, monad-transformers

There is simple abstract look up service with possibility to retrieve value by key:

```
trait LookUp[F[_]] {
  def read(key: String): F[Option[String]]
}
```

There is use case of this service, idea is to give implemented storage and accumulator with starting key, then ask for value from db if the result is None then stop and Return None, if the value is found then add it to accumulator list and look up for next value as key from previous call result. Execution stops when retrieved value already is found before or None is retrieved. Then a string of all acc elements is returned as result.

Tried like this:

```
def readWhileFound[F[_]: Monad](db: LookUp[F], acc: List[String]): F[Option[String]] = {
  for{ result <- db.read(acc.head)} yield result match {
    case Some(value) if(!acc.contains(value)) => readWhileFound(db, value::acc)
    case _ => acc.mkstring("")      
  }
}
```

But I'm not able to get types right getting mismatch errors like:

```
found   : F[cats.data.OptionT[[_]F[_],String]]
required: cats.data.OptionT[F,String]
```

Approach number 2:

```
def readWhileFound[F[_]: Monad](key: String, db: LookUp[F])(implicit m: Monad[F]): F[Option[String]] = {
  m.tailRecM((Option(key), List.empty[String])) { case (currentK, accum) =>
    currentK match {
      case Some(value) if(!accum.contains(value)) => m.pure(Left((db.read(value), value :: accum)))
      case _        => m.pure(Right(Some(accum.mkString(""))))
    }
  }
}
```

Getting compiler error:

```
(Found)  F[Option[String]]
required: Option[String]
case Some(value) if(!accum.contains(value)) => m.pure(Left((db.read(value), value :: accum)))
```

Looks like db.read(value) somehow should be unwrapped out of F

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you have to return `OptionT[F, String]` instead of `F[Option[String]]`? Also, you say "if the result is None then stop and Return None" but you try to return `OptionT.some`. If you actually never return a `None` your return type should just be `F[String]`.

Comment: It can be F[Option[String]] if it makes things easier.  F[None] should be returned if the first call of db.read(key) returns F[None]
if Some is returned, then put it in acc and  do iterations while None is returned or retrieved value already exists in acc then  return Some(acc.mkString(""))

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a great use case for **fs2**:

You should be able to do something like this:

```scala
import fs2.Stream

def readWhileFound[F[_]: Concurrent](db: LookUp[F])(initialKey: String): F[List[String] =
  Stream.unfoldEval(initialKey) { currentKey =>
    db.read(key = currentKey).map(k => (k, k))
  }.compile.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

You are `match`-ing on the wrong expression in your first implementation. You should `match` on `result`, not on the entire for-comprehension. The implementation below should do what you're after.

```
def readWhileFound[F[_]: Monad](db: LookUp[F], startKey: String): F[Option[String]] = {
  def loop(currKey: String, seenKeys: Set[String]): F[Option[String]] = {
    db.read(currKey).flatMap {
      case Some(nextKey) if !seenKeys.contains(nextKey) =>
        loop(nextKey, seenKeys + nextKey)

      case _ if seenKeys.nonEmpty => seenKeys.mkString("").some.pure[F]

      case _ => none[String].pure[F]
    }
  }

  loop(startKey, Set.empty)
}
```

I've replaced `List` with `Set` for the accumulated values because its `contains` method is more efficient, but if you care about the order in the returned result then you'll have to either go back to `List` (less efficient) or use two accumulators (one `Set`, the other `List`).